# How do you model transparent materials like light guides if transmittance is 90% for 0.5mm of sheet glass but 0.3db/km for fiber optics?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

I am trying to model a light guide (using a commercial tool - Synopsys Lighttools).  I am getting very low transmittance using glasses in the material library, on the order of 40% loss in the visible spectrum.  Those values seem low considering the performance of high purity glass used in fiber optics - I have a datasheet from Corning showing ~0.3db/km.

I would expect many more reflections in a fiber, and wanted to know how to accurately model the glass in my light guide.  My understanding is the transmittance test is measuring the ratio of light intensity when a sample is inserted between a source and a receiver.  All the sample data is for thin sections, generally under a millimeter whereas the light guide is 100s of millimeters long.

Can someone explain what magnitude to use in optics to get a correct value?

Comment: This is more an engineering question than physics. The answer is probably "talk to your glass vendor and ask what levels of transmittance they offer at what prices"

Comment: Agreed, but engineering is applied physics.  If we understand how one parameter is derived, we can get to a useful value of another.  Finding the right point of contact at the vendor is in process.

Comment: the question doesn't ask what's the cause or derivation of the optical loss, only how to model it and what values are appropriate. If you want to change the question, please edit the question to clarify (the comments are here to aid in improving the question, but the question should stand alone without needing to read the comments)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your glass values are. Is it 90% transmission or 40% loss. Are those for 0.5mm and a few hundred mm, respectively?

That obviously doesn't scale, so it must include reflection loss at the surface. Then we have two points and one line:

$$ 0.9 = (1-R) e^{-0.5{\rm mm}/L} $$
$$ 0.4 = (1-R) e^{-200{\rm mm}/L} $$

(Somewhat guessing the numbers...you can adjust as needed).

From that:

$$\frac{0.9}{0.4}=2.25 = e^{195.5/L} $$

so that characteristic loss length is:

$$L = \frac{195.5\,{\rm mm}}{\ln{2.25}} = 241\,{\rm mm}$$

With that:

$$ R = 8.3\,{\%}$$

There is no way to pull 0.3 db/km from those numbers.

The key for fibre optics is that the light is contained by total internal reflection (TIR) at the fiber boundary. If the medium outside the fibre is lossless, than the "T" in TIR is indeed "total". It may be nearly total for actual fiber in-use, and probably included in the 0.3 db/km.

Without clearer data, it's difficult to make further progress.

Comment: Sheet glass is ~90% transmittance at 0.5mm thickness.  Using that value in our light guide design yields 40% loss.  We are not using fibers, but fibers are light guides and getting the bulk internal transmittance value correct is what we are looking for.  We have a couple of data points for fibers of between 0.1 and 0.3 db/km at single frequencies, but nothing against visible spectrum.  The Fresnel losses as the light crosses the boundary into the fiber is not broken out.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but this software (Synopsys Lighttools) does not seem to be adequate for modeling fiber optics because it is [based on geometrical optics](http://file:///C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/october-2020-arvr-presentation-slides.pdf), whereas you may need Maxwell equations for fiber optics.

Comment: Not modelling fibers, but rather light guides of orders of magnitude greater thickness.

Comment: @JohnBucknell : Yes, but you wrote "I would expect many more reflections in a fiber", I am not sure if this is about what you calculate or what you compare with. If this is what you compare with, then, again, fibers (especially single-mode fibers) require Maxwell equations. By the way, you may calculate using a glass with zero losses, I suspect you will get pretty much the same results as with ~0.3db/km: most losses in the light guide may be due to less than perfect reflections.